# Join table on date column that falls between start and end date in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables - `#teacher` and `#kids`

I need to match a kid with his/her teacher depending on who was working that day.

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Code for tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #teacher
(
    teacher_name varchar(20),
    start_date date,
    end_date date
)

CREATE TABLE #kids
(
    child_name varchar(20),
    attendance date,
)

INSERT INTO #teacher
    SELECT 'Mary', '2017/01/01', '2017/10/10'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Jane', '2020/05/15', '2021/09/20'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Jenny', '2021/10/25', '2022/02/20'
    
    
INSERT INTO #kids
    SELECT 'Tommy', '2021/11/10'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Sadie', '2017/06/23'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Arthur', '2021/12/25'
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `join`. The join condition is exactly what you wrote in question title:

```
select k.child_name, k.attendance, t.teacher_name
from #kids k
left join #teachers t on k.attendance between t.start_date and t.end_date
```